# Calculate all possible values of utf8

Tags: c++, c++11, utf-8

I want to print all possible UTF-8 values. Something similar to this:

```
  uint32_t max = 0xFFFFFFFF;
  for (uint32_t i = 0; i <= max; i++)
  {
    std::cout << std::hex << i << std::endl;    
  }
```

But I'm printing a lot of impossible cases. Any better idea?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "impossible cases"?

Comment: Did you read eg. Wikipedia (and understood it)? Because your code is nonsense (if you want to print all possible utf8 byte tuples). Wikipedia clearly describes what restrictions exist for what byte length

Comment: In UTF-8, all charactes that stars with 0x10 are continuations of one utf8- char represented in more than 1 byte. Forr example 11100100 10xxxxx it's a valid case but 11100100 11xxxxx it's invalid for example.

Comment: That's going to take a while...

Comment: Right (that's not all, but a good start). So, any byte that is not the first one of it's sequence must start with the bits 10... where's that in your program?

Comment: I dont know how to do this exactly... thas my question

Comment: There is about one million of them. Are you sure you need them all?

Comment: That's a classic XY problem. Please ask about your problem, instead of your proposed solution (which cannot work).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why would you want to do this, but here you go:

```
int i = 0;
for(; i < 0x80; ++i) // 0xxxxxxx
    printf("%.2x\n", i);
for(; i < 0x800; ++i) // 110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
    printf("%.2x %.2x\n", 0xc0 | (i >> 6), 0x80 | (i & 0x3f));
for(; i < 0x10000; ++i) // 1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
    if(i < 0xd800 || i >= 0xe000) // skip surrogates
        printf("%.2x %.2x %.2x\n", 0xe0 | (i >> 12), 0x80 | ((i >> 6) & 0x3f), 0x80 | (i & 0x3f));
for(; i < 0x110000; ++i) // 11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
    printf("%.2x %.2x %.2x %.2x\n", 0xf0 | (i >> 18), 0x80 | ((i >> 12) & 0x3f), 0x80 | ((i >> 6) & 0x3f), 0x80 | (i & 0x3f));
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to store an array in my program with the precaulculated width in pixels of each possible utf-8 printable value, but there are a lot of possible cases i think.

Comment: @XabiE: this doesn't make sense. You should make yourself more familiar with Unicode. There is stuff like combining characters, etc.. Text rendering is a complex subject and your best bet is to query your text rendering engine what the sizes of the strings are.

Comment: I know, but unfortunattely I can't do this. Rendering engine is in another processor without comunication and I need to split my messages before draw it in my GUI, so i think a possible solution coluld be pre-calcualte the width of any possible utf8 char and store this information in an array for example.

Comment: @XabiE: This simply isn't going to work. But if you insist, you are welcome to do it your way.

Comment: I undestand what you said, but, because my particular app architecture, I cant query to the GUI server the width of my string before draw it. I know this is the best option, but (not for me) i cant do that. so I'm trying to find another solution. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @XabiE: Don't. No, seriously, just don't. This isn't going to work out. Calculating the width of a string is **way** (***WAY***) more involved, than summing up the widths of the individual code points. It'll fail for decomposed characters, for example, and some scripts render characters differently in isolation, than when used in a word. And then your text rendering engine is going to apply kerning. Now all bets are off. You might as well just `return 721;`. On average that's probably just as accurate as your well planned failure.

Comment: @XabiE Oh sorry, you want to do *width in pixels*, not *length*. Totally misunderstood you. It will still not work because of what IInspectable says, but if you have a fixed repertoire of *words* you can actually get away with this idea, by storing widths of words rather than individual characters.